# ExpandableListView doesn't expand group row

Tags: android

I have some strange behavior in ExpandavleListView

and group row like (and it works with checked)

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSelectHandleLeft="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
    </CheckedTextView>
```

I need to put additional data in row so I have tried like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        style="@style/row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        style="@style/row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@color/expanded_row_points"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

but it doesn't work.

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.row_merchant, null);
    }
    //((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
    return convertView;
}
```

Does anyone know what is a problem, why list doesn't expand when I use linearlayout and works when I use checkedtextview ?

Child View code

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    tempChild = (List<Model>) Childtem.get(groupPosition);
    TextView text = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.row_scheme, null);
    }
    text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText(tempChild.get(childPosition).name);
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, tempChild.get(childPosition).name,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: what is code for child view?

Comment: check that child count not equal to zero, what is code in child count??

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan Child count returns list size and is 1 in this case

Comment: every thing work fine in your code, Did you have debug your code to find out did going to child view or not? the below link is a example of custom expandable list, see that:
http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/